# if he/she reasonably believe -- no "s"?

Tags: genderless-pronouns

Example with [a context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-your-ground_law):

> In the United States, stand-your-ground law is a law that authorizes a person to protect and defend one's own life and limb against threat or perceived threat, and states that an individual has no duty to retreat from any place he/she has a lawful right to be and may use any level of force, including lethal, if **he/she** reasonably **believe** **he/she face** an imminent and immediate threat of serious bodily harm or death; as opposed to Duty to Retreat laws.

This is the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article on *stand-your-ground law*. The grammar looks rather strange. Do you think that kind of grammar is possible?

Comment: I suspect that what has happened here is that this originally had gender-neutral *they*, and this was later changed it to *he/she* without correcting the verbs. In any case, it's just a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.  @StoneyB is probably right.

Third person regular singular verbs end in "s" or "es".

English does not have a strong, official gender-neutral third person pronoun other than *it*, which is impersonal - it's inappropriate to use *it* when referring to a person.

So things like this are needed.

> He or she believes that ...
>
> He/she believes that ...

"He or she" is not treated as plural.

However - you'll probably hear this in informal speech quite a bit - if the antecedent is a person but of unknown gender, many will use *they*/*them*.  This is treated as plural like any other use of *they*, even though it refers to one person.  It's not really considered proper English but I hear it a lot (but don't really read it a lot).

> So to get your driver's license you have to pay the fee to the clerk.
>
> Do they take debit cards or only cash?

Comment: Using [*they* as a singular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) instead of something like *he/she* is actually a well-established thing though, as Wikipedia says, "acceptance varies". I wouldn't call it incorrect or improper.